# Android freezes on 'aligning project1.dpk'

Tags: android, delphi

I am compiling an android application with phone connected. 
However just prior to application being viewed on the phone it suddenly freezes
(on aligning project1.dpk) and fires up the Android SDK Manager.
I have everything installed from the android tools so I have no idea why does the manager show. When I close the manager it displays a warning message :

[image]

However when I look into the running processes the adb.exe (32 bit) is already running (!).
I have Android SDK tools 25.2.25 already installed.
Also Android SDK Platform Tools 28.0.0. 
Also I have everything under Android 9 (api 28) installed.
So is the Google USB Driver installed.
Checking up on the SDK paths everything seems fine :

[image]

So before I suffer a mental breakdown, can someone tell me what is wrong here ? Why I can not see the application on the phone?
On the phone I have USB debugging enabled.Install via USB is also enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SDK path settings are not correct.

ZipAlign entry points to SDKManager.exe instead of zipalign.exe.

Proper path settings should be (appended to base SDK path)

```
ZipAlign location (other build tools versions besides 28.0.3 can be used)
\build-tools\28.0.3\zipalign.exe

Android location
\tools\Android.bat

Adb location
\platform-tools\Adb.exe

Aapt location
\build-tools\28.0.3\aapt.exe

SDK API level location (it does not have to be 28)
\platforms\android-28
```

Comment: ahhh.... :)  This is what happens when you rely on Delphi to warn you of the wrong path. Thank you Dalija. Puno hvala.